# Is there a way to set a transition speed on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a CSS way or even a javascript way to set a transition speed when swapping images on mouse over? I haven't tried anything so there is no code to provide. I'm wondering if it can me done and an example. Thanks!

HTML

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li class="link1"><a href="index.html"></a></li>
<li class="link2"><a href="services.html"></a></li>
<li class="link3"><a href="contact.html"></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li.link1 {
background-image: url(../images/home.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 15px;
width: 66px;
background-position: left top;
}
li.link1:hover {
background-image: url(../images/home.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 15px;
width: 66px;
background-position: left bottom;   
}
```

Comment: You should be able to set a transition speed on image swapping, through the normal techniques.  Then just hang that off of a function that you call on mouseover

Comment: Assign the transition to the `:hover` pseudo-selector: http://jsfiddle.net/fNGdK/

Comment: @Rob that just moves the image. It doesn't swap them.

Comment: @Ibanez It was just a quick example to show how to apply different transitions speeds. The example used `left`, but you can also use `opacity`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery hover

Suppose you have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div id="element" style="position:relative;">
   <img src="image1.gif" id="img1" />
   <img src="image2.gif" id="img2" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

and css :

```
img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#element").hover(function() {
    //fadeout first image using jQuery fadeOut
    $("#img1").fadeOut(200);
    //fadein second image using jQuery fadeIn 
    $("#img2").fadeIn(200);
}, function () {
    //fadeout second image using jQuery fadeOut
    $("#img1").fadeIn(200);
    //fadein first image using jQuery fadeIn
    $("#img2").fadeOut(200);
});
```

check below link

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7zFb/) for demo

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7zFb/1/) using css3 and jQuery.hover as fallback for ie as mentioned by [hustlerinc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253000/hustlerinc)

Answer (score 0):

yes there is. the first thing you have to specify though is how you're performing the swap.

if there are two layers on top of each other and you're transitioning opacity of them **via CSS**, then you'd set transition (-webkit, -moz, -o, etc) opacity 1s; where 1s refers to the number in seconds.

if you're doing the transitions **via jquery, or another javascript framework,** then your animation functions will have an additional available parameter for a speed in milliseconds, like .animate( {properties xyz}, 200 );

Comment: Right now I'm just using CSS to move the position of a background image. I would like to slow down the transition to make it look more natural. I'm trying to make it look like it's being pushed down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS3, here's the first result on Google:

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: @Ibanez : use css3 transition for all browsers except ie and jQuery hover as a fallback for ie

Comment: I added my code for the list item I would like to transition. I have not figured out how to make it happen with the above code.